# Find string in one file and use it in another file

Tags: awk

In `file 1` I need to find lines that contain string `hdu` in column 2 (or `HX*` in column 5), and then in `file 2` replace the value in the column 2 with value of column 5 from `file 1`.

file1:

```
64 ha 1 LIG H64 64 0.000000 12.0100 c 0.637086 12.0100
65 du 1 LIG XX65 65 0.000000 16.0000 o -0.547014 16.0000
66 du 1 LIG XX66 66 0.000000 16.0000 oh -0.611114 16.0000
67 hdu 1 LIG HX67 67 0.000000 1.0080 hc 0.090186 1.0080
68 hdu 1 LIG HX68 68 0.000000 1.0080 hc 0.090186 1.0080
```

file2:

```
1LIG    H64   64    2.06144000    1.94117000    2.65125000
1LIG   XX65   65    2.14737000    1.92392000    2.73722000
1LIG   XX66   66    1.98154000    2.05095000    2.64407000
1LIG   XX67   67    2.21440000    1.72650000    2.55862000
1LIG   XX68   68    2.22046000    1.85502000    2.43909000
```

In the given case, I need to replace `XX67` with `HX67`, and `XX68` with `HX68`, so that the output is:

```
1LIG    H64   64    2.06144000    1.94117000    2.65125000
1LIG   XX65   65    2.14737000    1.92392000    2.73722000
1LIG   XX66   66    1.98154000    2.05095000    2.64407000
1LIG   HX67   67    2.21440000    1.72650000    2.55862000
1LIG   HX68   68    2.22046000    1.85502000    2.43909000
```

My best guess was command

`awk 'FNR==NR && $2=="hdu" {x=$1;y=$5} NR!=FNR { if ($3==x) {$2=y} print}' file1 file2`

but it replaced only last occurrence.

Comment: Are the two files the same length?

Comment: no, they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your `x` and `y` values are overwritten, and thus only the last line of file1 will persist. Try this small adaption of your one-liner using an array:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && $2=="hdu" {y[$1] = $5} NR!=FNR { if ($3 in y) {$2 = y[$3]} print} ' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you. I does the job, however, I have small problem with formatting in the output file. The file that I am preparing needs to maintain original formatting, but after this command, it loses the extra spaces. Is there a way to maintain original formatting?